ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras.layers.core'
I am trying to import LSTM in python
from keras.layers.core import Layer, InputSpec

However, I get below error message on compilation:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras.layers.core'

Can somebody please help me out with this?

Those are not the right imports, only import from keras.layers, not any internal import.

You are possibly having this error due to changes in the Keras API in recent versions. You can import Layer and InputSpec directly from keras.layers. Your import statement should be:
from keras.layers import Layer, InputSpec

